# Iterate through Strings and test for differences in characters

Tags: swift, string

I am trying to iterate through a series of characters similar to this

```
//Example.txt
0 X X X 0
0 X 0 X 0
0 0 X 0 0
0 X 0 X 0
0 X X X 0
```

I want to be able to tell the difference between the X's and the 0's. The code I am currently using cause an infinite loop to run and then my app never finishes building.

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Example.txt", ofType: nil)
do {
    let fileContents = try String(contentsOfFile:path!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    let lines = fileContents.components(separatedBy: "\n")

     for row in 0..<lines.count {
     let items = lines[row].components(separatedBy: " ")

         for column in 0..<items.count {
                    print(column,row)
             }
         }
     } catch {
         print("Error loading map")
     }
```

It will Iterate through the .txt document perfectly fine, it just won't finish building and running, it gets stuck on the white loading screen. I think it has something to do with the encoding of the text

How can I fix the infinite loop bug, and tell the difference between the different characters that I intend to add in later.

**-Edit-**

I figured out how to test the characters to tell the difference between them using-

```
for row in 0..<lines.count {
let items = lines[row].components(separatedBy: " ")

    for column in 0..<items.count {

        if items[1] == "0" {
            print("0")
        } else {
            print("X")
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is that it treats each row in the document as an array so the *items* line when testing reaches an array out-of-bounds error.

Comment: If your app does not build then it cannot *"iterate through the .txt document perfectly"* or *"cause an infinite loop to run*

Comment: it starts to build but because it infinitely loops it never actually finishes building. Edited my question to clarify

Comment: You should be checking each column not each items. `let lines = fileContents.components(separatedBy: .newlines) for line in lines {
    let columns = line.components(separatedBy: " ")
    for column in columns {
        print(column)
    }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the "column" variable inside your inner for. In fact, on every iteration, you're always comparing the second element of the "items" array (`items[1]`) against *"0"*. If the items array has less than 2 elements, it will cause an out-of-bounds error.

Perhaps you should iterate as follows (I suggest using "for in" loops):

```
for line in lines {
    let items = line.components(separatedBy: " ")
    for item in items {
        if item == "0" {
            print("0")
        } else {
            print("X")
        }
    }
}
```

Although I don't understand your "if else", if the file can only contain either "0" or "X" and you're only visualizing it, you might as well just `print(item)` instead.

Comment: oh duh! never would have guessed to test each item in *items*. Thanks a lot works exactly like I needed. :)